# Expected expression occurs in C

Tags: c, variables, conditional-statements, expression, local

What I am doing here is, measuring 8 bit of IR sensor data. Here `Reflectance_Read(time)` returns the 8 bit IR sensor data in Binary form.
Then taking the middle two sensors value, bit number 3 and 4 from the `Data` variable as `Right` and `Left` variable, I tried to return something like `OffRoad`, `OnRoad` etc.

```
#define OffRoad = 0x0
#define OffToLeft = 0x1
#define OffToRight = 0x2
#define OnRoad = 0x3
#define LeftCheck = 0x10
#define RightCheck = 0x08
uint8_t Reflectance_Center(uint32_t time){

    uint8_t Data;
    uint8_t Left, Right;
    Reflectance_Init();
    Data = Reflectance_Read(time);
    Left = Data&0x10;
    Right = Data&0x08;
    if(0){}
    else if(Left==LeftCheck && Right==RightCheck) return OnRoad;
    else if(Left==LeftCheck && Right!=RightCheck) return OffToRight;
    else if(Left!=LeftCheck && Right==RightCheck) return OffToLeft;
    else if(Left!=LeftCheck && Right!=RightCheck) return OffRoad;
    return 0;
}
```

But I got an error from `else if(Left==LeftCheck && Right==RightCheck) return OnRoad;` this line saying `error #29: expected an expression`. I can't figure it out what is causing the error.

```
#define OFFROAD 0x0
#define OFFTOLEFT 0x1
#define OFFTORIGHT 0x2
#define ONROAD 0x3
#define LEFTCHECK 0x10
#define RIGHTCHECK 0x08
```

I've changed my `#define` in the correct form.
My Problem is Solved!

Comment: We can't see line 137. Put the code in the question as text. From [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#define LeftCheck = 0x010;`

That syntax is incorrect (or well, at least it's probably not what you intend).
Change it to
`#define Leftcheck 0x010`

Also applies to all other of your defines.

Comment: thank you, but still I get expression error in `else if(Left==LeftCheck && Right==RightCheck) return OnRoad;` this line

Comment: Show us your new code, **add** it to your question, don't delete the old code. Presumably you have _not_ corrected all `#define'' lines. Oh, and this time, _please post the source verbatim, not as screenshot._